# Fixing position and responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble with positioning of my design. The idea was to create a circle flow with a text-box on hover in the middle. I've made it works on my website but whenever I decrease the screen resolution, it's messed up. I'm new with css, and wondering if there's any simple way to create this design?

```
    .circle {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 85px;
  background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.1);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00fcff;
}


.hoverWrapper1:hover #hoverShow1 {
 display: block;
}

.hoverWrapper1 #hoverShow1 {
 display: none;
}

.hoverWrapper2:hover #hoverShow2 {
 display: block;
}

.hoverWrapper2 #hoverShow2 {
 display: none;
}

.hoverWrapper3:hover #hoverShow3 {
 display: block;
}

.hoverWrapper3 #hoverShow3 {
 display: none;
}

.hoverWrapper4:hover #hoverShow4 {
 display: block;
}

.hoverWrapper4 #hoverShow4 {
 display: none;
}

.hoverWrapper5:hover #hoverShow5 {
 display: block;
}

.hoverWrapper5 #hoverShow5 {
 display: none;
}

.hoverWrapper6:hover #hoverShow6 {
 display: block;
}

.hoverWrapper6 #hoverShow6 {
 display: none;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #00fcff;
} 

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 29%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  right: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #00fcff;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background: rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.1);
}

    <div class="hoverWrapper1">
  <button class="circle" style="position:absolute; top: 3%; right: 63%; color:#00fcff; font-size: 120%;">Strategy</button>
    <div id="hoverShow1" class="absolute" style="color: white;">Even strategy is no longer what it used to be. We all live in a VUCA World. (volatile, uncertain, complex and ambiguous) and the 20th Century style business plans will be obsolete before implementation begins. We will help you prepare, act and respond to this new order – we can even fast track your team’s learning just when they need it.<</div></div>

<div class="hoverWrapper2">
  <button class="circle" style="position:absolute; top: 27%;right: 30%; color:#00fcff;font-size: 120%;">Employees</button>
    <div id="hoverShow2" class="absolute">block B</div></div>

<div class="hoverWrapper3">
   <button class="circle" style="position:absolute; top:27%;right: 95%; color:#00fcff;font-size: 120%;">Customers</button>
      <div id="hoverShow3" class="absolute">block C</div></div>

<div class="hoverWrapper4">
  <button class="circle" style="position:absolute; top: 55%;right: 30%; color:#00fcff;font-size: 120%;">Business Model</button>
    <div id="hoverShow4" class="absolute">block D</div></div>

<div class="hoverWrapper5">
  <button class="circle" style="position:absolute; top: 55%;right: 95%; color:#00fcff;font-size: 120%;">Markets</button>
    <div id="hoverShow5" class="absolute">block E</div></div>

<div class="hoverWrapper6">
  <button class="circle" style="position:absolute; top: 75%;right: 63%; color:#00fcff;font-size: 120%;">Change</button>
    <div id="hoverShow6" class="absolute">block F</div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/luxs_/axshfe1z/3/

Comment: Define "messed up".

Comment: @Thomas the circles and textbox overlap with each other

Comment: There is no way to prevent overlapping automatically if you use absolute positioning. The best you can do is to strictly define size per each element or add a script that does it automatically for your cases.

Comment: @ViktorYakubiv is there any way other than using absolute positioning to achieve the same design? I'm not really familiar with scripting

Comment: At some point it's just not going to fit. Consider using percentages or `vw`/`vh`/`vmin`/`vmax` units for sizing, maybe combined with `max-width`/`max-height` depending on what you want. A lot is possible with CSS, but you need to make it clear for yourself how you want it to behave, first.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, my code works on my website but it whenever I change the screen ratio, it all messed up. And I'll try using vw/vh